# Scala: Passing Vs applying function

Tags: function, scala

Let's say we have the following code snippet:

```
  List(1, 2, 3) 
  .map(doubleIt) // passing function
  .map(x => doubleIt(x)) // applying function

   def doubleIt(i: Int): Int = 2 * i
```

As you can see we can either pass `doubleIt` as a function literal or apply it inside another anonymous Lambda. I have always wondered which approach is better. I personally prefer passing a function literal as it seems like second approach would end up creating an extra wrapper Lambda for no good reason, but I am not 100% positive my reasoning is correct.

I am curious to know what the pro/cons of each style are and whether one is definitely better than the other.

Comment: Small point of terminology: the second is a "function literal", but not the first.

Comment: In fact, the two forms are identical. The _Scala_ compiler implicitly converts the first form to the second. Both tell the _Scala_ compiler to create a new list by applying the `doubleIt` function to each member of the list.

As for style, the second form is more verbose and so has more explicit behavior, while the first is terser and likely to be preferred by _Scala_ veterans. It's a matter of personal preference, I guess.

Comment: Also, if `doubleIt` is not used anywhere else, I'd personally prefer the third option: `List(1,2,3).map{_ * 2}`

Comment: @MikeAllen That's not quite right; see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it depends somewhat on what your "function" is. If it is actually a function (that is, a function value, defined as `val doubleIt = (x: Int) => 2 * x`), then your hunch is correct. The version in which you pass a function literal that simply applies `doubleIt` (i.e., `l map { x => doubleIt(x) }` is compiled just as written, resulting in an anonymous function that delegates to `doubleIt`. Passing `doubleIt` as a function value takes out the middle man. If `doubleIt` is a method, on the other hand, then both forms are compiled identically.

You can easily verify this yourself at the REPL. Define the following class:

```
class A {
   val l = List(1,2,3)
   val f = (x: Int) => 2 * x
   def g(x: Int) = 2 * x

   def m1 = l map f
   def m2 = l map { x => f(x) }
   def m3 = l map g
   def m4 = l map { x => g(x) }
}
```

Then run `:power` and `:javap -v A`.

That said, the distinction is unlikely to make a practical difference in any but the most performance-critical code.  In ordinary circumstances, code clarity is the more important consideration and depends somewhat on who will be reading your code in the future. Personally, I tend to prefer the concise `lst map doubleIt` form; this form eliminates a bunch of syntactic noise that adds nothing semantically. I suppose the longer form may be considered more explicit, especially for developers that aren't very familiar with the `map` method. The literal reading matches the intent quite well: "(Given) list, map (each) x to doubleIt(x)". Your team will have to decide what's best for you and your organization.

Answer (score 3):

This might change in Scala 2.12+, but at the moment both approaches are identical. As a test, I created the following:

```
class Test {
  def testPassingFunction: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3).map(doubleIt)

  def testApplyingFunction: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3).map(x => doubleIt(x))

  def doubleIt(i: Int): Int = 2 * i
}
```

I then compiled it and used `javap` to disassemble the bytecode. Both functions are identical (except for different Strings. In all cases a new class that extends from `Function1` is created that calls the appropriate method. As @Mike says in the comments, the Scala compiler converts everything to the second form.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you test what happens if `doubleIt` is already a function value?

Comment: @AaronNovstrup is correct. If you define `doubleIt` as `val doubleIt = (i: Int) => 2*i`, `doubleIt` is already a value of type `Function1` so no wrapping is necessary in `List(1,2,3).map(doubleIt)`. However, in `List(1,2,3).map(x => doubleIt(x))` you are specifically telling the compiler to create a new `Function1` object that, in essence, forwards the call to the `Function1` object you already have.